# can't set type = "class" in predict.rpart

Tags: r, machine-learning, predict, rpart

I am trying to use decision tree classification on my dataset which contains 2 features and 1 dependent variable that looks like:
Age Salary Purchased(Y/N)

26  43000   0

17  57000   0

19  76000   0

27  58000   0

27  84000   0

32  150000  1

25  33000   0

If I use

```
classifier = rpart(formula = Purchased ~ ., data = training_set)
```

I get the result like

> 2           4          5          9
>   0.03296703 0.03296703 0.03296703 0.03296703

I need to get not the probability but the most likely result. But when I use

```
y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test_set[-3], type = 'class')
```

I get

> Error in predict.rpart(classifier, newdata = test_set[-3], type =
>   "class") :    Invalid prediction for "rpart" object

Can you help me with that?

Comment: what do you get for `class(training_set$Purchased)` ?

Comment: class(training_set$Purchased) returns integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. I should have encoded the dependent variable as a factor:

```
dataset$Purchased = factor(dataset$Purchased, levels = c(0, 1))
```

After adding this line everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the same problem who does not find the above solutions helpful. I had the same problem with the `predict` function in the 'rpart' package and just uninstalled another package that also had a `predict` function. So that might be worth looking at; in my case, I had to uninstall the 'Harvest.tree' package.

A second way to access a function that is masked by another package ist to explicitly specify the namespace calling it with `rpart::predict(...)`. That way you can keep all packages and you do not have to find out which package exactly causes the masking.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).